# frameset in HTML, problems in calling script

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript, I am writing this simple code to display an URL inside a frame,  I dont know what the reason is but its not working.

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>  
    </body>
    <frameset  style="width:1000px; height:500px; border:1px solid black;">
            <frame NAME="fow_report">

            </frame>
        </frameset>
    <script>
        var ele = document.getElementsByName("fow_report")[0];
        ele.document.src="www.google.com";
    </script>
</html>
```

I am having this error in the console
**index.html:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined**

Comment: you don't have any tags with `name=frame`. You have a name of `fow_report`. either do `getElementsByTagName('frame')`, or `getElementsByName('fow_report')`

Comment: @MarcB I have updated the question.

Comment: and your html is illegal. you can either have a frameset, or you can have a body. not both.

Comment: so the question now is I want to display an URL in a frame using javascript, how can I do that.?

Answer (score 0):

Super Cool Handsom Gel Boy beat me to the post, but I also use iframe's. You also are calling `ele.document.src =`, but you only need `ele.src =`

```js
var ele = document.getElementsByName('fow_report')[0];
ele.src = 'http://www.bing.com';
```

```html
<iframe name="fow_report" style="width:1000px; height:500px; border:1px solid black;"></iframe>
```

Here's a sample jsfiddle*: https://jsfiddle.net/n9z3gng1/1/

*Note that the contents will not be displayed because jsfiddle runs over https, but those sites will not allow their https side to display through a frame.